# How can I change the number of items in a views View only for the first page?

Tags: views, paging

**Hi my friends!**

This problem is described in [an old post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74977/how-can-i-change-the-number-of-items-in-a-view-only-for-the-first-page) which has a solution.

The solution works well. But not perfectly. I explain.

I have 15 items. I set Views to display 8 items per page. But I want to show 7 ítems in the first page.

Everything works fine except pager. I have 15 items:

- **7 items** in the 1st page
- **8 items** in the 2nd page
- **Total: 15 items**.

The pager should be 2 pages. But the pager shows 3 pages. If I click on the 3rd page of the pager, it leads me to the **&page=2**. Which contains no items.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try DnBase's answer?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But the pager is independent of Views. Or not?